# How to properly count multiples of a factor within a range with a for loop? (C# Beginner)

Tags: c#, for-loop, range, counting

Given 3 int's "start", "end", and "factor", using a loop, count how many multiples of "factor" occur between start and end (inclusive).

I was given this question on a lab for my first programming class. I've been stuck on it for a few days now, and whenever I reach out for help with what I could be doing wrong, I'm given really vague "yep somethings definitely not right there" responses and I get stuck in an endless loop of trying to figure out what's wrong so I can google it.

I've tried a few different iterations of code, some have come close but still not right.

```
public static int Test1(int start, int end, int factor)
        {
            
            for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                int result = i % factor;                    
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

```
public static int Test1(int start, int end, int factor)
        {
            
            for(int i = 0; start <= end; i++)
            {
                if(start + factor <= end)
                {
                    factor++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

```
 public static int Test1(int start, int end, int factor)
        {
            for (int i = 0; start <= end; i++)
            {
                if (start + factor < end)
                {
                    start+=factor;
                }
                else
                {
                    return i;
                }

            }

            return 0;
        }
```

Expected result:
if (for example) start = 14; end = 35; factor = 3;
result should equal 7 multiples of 3, outputting 7.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. what I did is I made a loop from start to end and in math we know that the multiple of somthing times the amount of times it is devided in equals the original number(int this case a number between start to end) so I made a condition that reflects that and finally returned count.

```
public static int Multiple(int start , int end , int factor)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            if(i == factor * (i / factor))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code here is maybe the most near :

```
public static int Test1(int start, int end, int factor)
        {
            
            for(int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            {
                int result = i % factor;                    
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

But the problem is when you find a factor, you return "i". About other examples I don't understand how it may work.

Just use that :

```
public static int Test1(int start, int end, int factor)
{
    int numberFound = 0;
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        if( i % factor==0);
        {
            numberFound++;
        }
    }

    return numberFound;
}
```

When i%factor = 0, this means it found one, so on the end you have the quantity of multipliers to return.

Comment: _When i%factor = 0, this means it found one_ <-- I think it would help OP if you explained _why_ `i % factor == 0` means it found one.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static int Test1(int start, int end, int factor)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int result = 0;
            for (i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                result = (end/factor)-(start/factor);
                
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: What's the point of doing `result = (end/factor)-(start/factor);` in a loop over the variable `i`?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should add explanation.